# Have all the hyperlinks stored in AllHyperLinks but when i try to run this code

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink

Have all the hyperlinks stored in `AllHyperLinks` but when i try to run this code. it will not click the link with the `CAB D Pair` word. But when i try to debug `(F8)`, it will proceed with the click command.

```
Set AllHyperLinks = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
   For Each hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
      If hyper_link.innerText = "CAB D Pair " Then
         hyper_link.Click
   Exit For
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: Can you try to indent your code properly? Maybe the error comes from ending for before if.

Comment: how do i do that? i just copy paste the code

Comment: Please edit you question to easily understand by other developers. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to indent your code. Use proper indention.

Comment: @HensonIbon https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: done modification. sorry for that first time to code and use this page. thanks.